# How to create and enter a directory in linux?

Tags: linux, sh

How to create and enter a directory in GNU/Linux ?

```
mkdir Pics | cd Pics
```

Gives :

```
bash: cd: Pics: No such file or directory
```

Comment: @Limey, I can't believe there is abbreviation for that!!!

Comment: @Limey - I was about to ask what that acronym meant, but I googled it instead.  For the OP, this question doesn't belong here for two reasons.  It shows little research effort, and it's more about being a power user than about programming.

Comment: And when I googled it I found ... nothing directly helpful.

Comment: I didn't know the answer to this question when I looked at it, I googled it.  First 5 links all had the answer.

Comment: @Limey here was my google search : https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+create+and+enter+directories+in+linux&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs . Funnily the only thing relevant was my own question. I suggest you open http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html scroll to the bottom of the document and read the `How To Answer Questions in a Helpful Way` section. Be helpful instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `;` between commands. So

```
mkdir Pics; cd Pics
```

What you have written is called a pipe. That means the output of the first program is used as the input to the other, which doesn't make sense because the output of `mkdir` is nothing or an error and `cd` doesn't read from input.

**By the way**, ask questions like this in [super user](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 4):

The pipe `|` sends the output of the first to the second command as input.

what you need to use is a `;`

```
mkdir Pics; cd Pics
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following

```
mkdir Pics; cd Pics
```

The pipe character is not appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

To do multiple commands in one line, you use a semicolon instead of a pipe.

`mkdir Pics ; cd Pics`